# Displaying posts thumbnails in Wordpress show only first thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display on the sidebar the latest posts title and thumbnail.
So far I'm getting the posts title and only one thumbnail duplicated.
You can see the result [here](http://www.emaze.com/blog/).(only the first/oldest post image displaying)

Here is my code:

```
$rps = wp_get_recent_posts($params);
foreach($rps as $rp) :
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID
             );

    $attachment = current(get_posts( $args ));
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($rp['ID']);?>"><?php echo $rp['post_title'];?><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks for any tips/assistance given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `'post_parent' => $post->ID` with `'post_parent' => $rp['ID']` . That's it.
What you are doing is, you are passing current post's ID in $args for all posts.

Answer (score -1):

run 2 [queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

one outputs the first post. The second outputs everything else excluding the first

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_parent' => $post->ID);  
$first = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $first->have_posts() ) : $first->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $first->ID, 'thumbnail' );?></a>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php $args2 = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'offset' => 1);  
$rest = new WP_Query( $args2 );
while ( $rest->have_posts() ) : $rest->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $rest->ID, 'thumbnail' );?></a>
 <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```